# How to get notes2bib to work with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, notes2bib

I have been using a great package called `notes2bib` that works perfectly with `natbib`. However, when I try to move to using `biber`/`biblatex` it stops working quite so well. It technically works fine, however it ignores my setting to put all the citations into superscripts.

Here is a MWE of it working perfectly with  `natbib`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWEnatbib.bib}
@Article{Brown,
    author ="Brown, Matthew L. and Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Hartling, David and Jean, Anthony and Merbouh, Nabyl",
    title  ="Three-dimensional printing of ellipsoidal structures using Mercury",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2018",
    doi  ="10.1039/C7CE01901G",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{notes2bib}

\usepackage[super]{natbib} 

\begin{document}
This is example text\cite{Brown}.
Now this is text that needs a bibnote\bibnote[calipers]{Structure measured with calipers and rounded to the nearest}.
Now I need to refer to that bibnote again.\citenote{calipers}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{MWEnatbib}


\end{document}
```

And here is leaving the citations as [1] instead of making them superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{MWEbiblatex.bib}
@Article{Brown,
    author ="Brown, Matthew L. and Van Wieren, Ken and Tailor, Hamel N. and Hartling, David and Jean, Anthony and Merbouh, Nabyl",
    title  ="Three-dimensional printing of ellipsoidal structures using Mercury",
    journal  ="CrystEngComm",
    year  ="2018",
    doi  ="10.1039/C7CE01901G",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{notes2bib}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWEbiblatex.bib}

\begin{document}
This is example text\autocite{Brown}.
Now this is text that needs a bibnote\bibnote[calipers]{Structure measured with calipers and rounded to the nearest}.
Now I need to refer to that bibnote again.\citenote{calipers}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I suspect that this works due to one redefining the `\cite` command whereas the other uses `\autocite`, but I don't know how to work around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `cite-function` option in the `notes2bib` documentation (page 4) for setting the citation command used by `notes2bib` internally. It defaults to using `\cite`, but for your purposes you can set it to use `\autocite` instead, which will give you the output you want.

So, either specify it as a package option:

```latex
% Make sure the biblatex package is loaded before the notes2bib package
%  or the commands won't be defined
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{MWEbiblatex.bib}
  
\usepackage[cite-function=\autocite]{notes2bib}
```

Or you can use the notes2bib package setup command to specify it afterwards:

```latex
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\bibnotesetup{cite-function=\autocite}
```

And, yes, as far as I can tell, the `natbib` example works because your options to the package redefine the cite command, which would otherwise use the basic numeric `[1]` formatting. The `chem-rsc` style sets the `\autocite` style to superscript, but doesn't touch the basic `\cite` command.

Comment: Thank you! That is perfect. Slightly embarrassed to have missed that.